# Colocar o erro em minha view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Como faço para jogar essas mensagem em minha view?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código que retorna as mensagem:

```
public ActionResult SaveInternalAuditRecord(InternalAuditRecord criticalAnalysisRecord, string idResponsibles, string idAuditors)
{
     if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ModelState.OrderByKeys(criticalAnalysisRecord.GetValidationOrder());
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        return Json(ModelState.GetModelStateErros());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu acho que o melhor neste caso seria criar uma partialView onde você trabalharia os erros e, então, usaria na tela e retornaria a PartialView;

Exemplo:

1 - Partial com erro: "_ValidationSummary.cshtml"

```
@if (!Html.ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
{
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <p class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Alerta!</p>
        <div class="validation-summary-errors">
                @foreach (var modelState in ViewData.ModelState.Values)
                {
                    foreach (ModelError error in modelState.Errors)
                    {
                        //aqui você tem seus erros. Trabalhe neles no padrão que precisar.
                    }
                }
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Controller:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;

public ActionResult SaveInternalAuditRecord(InternalAuditRecord criticalAnalysisRecord, string idResponsibles, string idAuditors)
{
     if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ModelState.OrderByKeys(criticalAnalysisRecord.GetValidationOrder());
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        return Json(new
            {
                RenderPartialToString("~/Views/Layout/_ValidationSummary.cshtml", null, ControllerContext, string.Empty)
            }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);;
    }
}

private string RenderPartialToString(string viewPath, object model, ControllerContext controllerContext, string partialFieldName)
        {
            var viewData = new ViewDataDictionary();
            var tempData = new TempDataDictionary();
            viewData.Model = model;

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(partialFieldName))
            {
                viewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = partialFieldName;
            }

            using (var sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controllerContext, viewPath);
                var viewContext = new ViewContext(controllerContext, viewResult.View, viewData, tempData, sw);

                if (controllerContext != null)
                    foreach (var item in controllerContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState.Where(item => item.Value.Errors.Any()))
                        viewContext.ViewData.ModelState.Add(item);

                viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

                return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
            }
        }
```

aí você só da o replace com seu ajax, assim como já está fazendo no seu código;

Comment: return PartialView() faz o knockoutjs para de funcionar estava usando assim

Comment: Editei a minha resposta @BrunoH. Agora ele vai montar o html no seu controller e vai retornar como string. Aí só você colocar no seu html via ajax

Comment: o ideal seria você colocar esse método RenderPartialToString em uma classe utilitaria e deixar o método estatico.

Comment: Ele deu alguns erro, porém agora estou trazendo as mensagem só que não está desenhado certo vem um " " parece editei.

Comment: Ele adiciona uma <li></li> a mais

Comment: Ah sim, entendi. Isso é o  @Html.ValidationSummary() que faz. Você pode olhar uma maneira de trazer manualmente os seus erros. Vou procurar aqui e edito a minha resposta pra te ajudar.

Comment: Vou atualizar a imagem

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62459/discussion-between-bruno-h-and-ayrton-giffoni).